# Connecting to a java:comp/env/... resource

Tags: jpa, glassfish, websphere, jndi, payara

In my `persistence.xml` file I have the following connection defined...

```
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/jee</jta-data-source>
```

It works well in WebSphere (in fact it's the only way I can get WebSphere to work correctly) with JPA.  It also worked with TomEE.

However when I deploy it in Payara/Glassfish I get the following error

> com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:comp/env/jdbc/jee__pm

I have verified that I enabled `Allow Non Component Callers` in the connection pool configuration.

I also added a `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml` and `glassfish-application.xml` with the resource refs defined as

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/jdbc/jee</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/jee</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/jee</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/jee</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: I wonder if I should just delete this as I had a more generic version of this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809960/what-to-put-into-jta-data-source-of-persistence-xml-that-works-on-all-vendors

Comment: I posted an answer in the other question. If it answers this question too, I'd close it.